# Capacity of Django Development server

Tags: python, django

I have a django powered website which allows uploading/downloading of some event, where event contain fields like geocode, some text, an image.

Hopefully the events would be around 1000-1500 at max but they might come simultaneously.
Can django development server handle the pilot load or should I shift to standard web server(will have to do some changes for that)?

Comment: you should definitely switch, django dev server is pretty much a toy, a simple single threaded server easily used for development, there are very few steps involved with serving your django application using apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should definitely switch, django dev server is pretty much a toy, a simple single threaded server easily used for development, there are very few steps involved with serving your django application using apache –

If someone uploads a large image, the server will block all other requests during that time, I believe that alone is good enough reason to switch servers.

Additionally, advice from the first page tutorial in django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server):

> Now’s a good time to note: don’t use this server in anything
>   resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for use while
>   developing. (We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
>   servers.)